# Wrapping chained method calls on a separate line in Eclipse for Java

Tags: eclipse, line

I haven't been successful in figuring out how to wrap each method call in `Eclipse`. For example, I have this:

```
someObject.A().B().C();
```

But I really want this:

```
someObject.A()
          .B()
          .C();
```

Nothing under the "Line Wrapping" section in `Eclipse` seems to give me this result.

Comment: Several years down the line I still don't think Eclipse does this well. The answers all have unwanted side effects or fail to do the job. I don't have an answer either (so I won't post one), but my workaround is to end each line with comments: someObject.A() // (new line) .B() // (new line) .C(); which works.

Answer (score 212):

Complementing Deepak Azad's answer, what you exactly need is the following:

> **Windows**: Window → Preferences → Java → Code Style 
>   → Formatter → Edit → Line wrapping (tab)
>
> **Mac OS**: ADT → Preferences → Java → Code Style 
>   → Formatter → Edit → Line wrapping (tab)

Then, in the list at the left, select:

> Function Calls → Qualified invocations

Now below this list, set **Line wrapping policy** to:

> Wrap all elements, except first element if not necessary

**Check**:

> Force split, even if line shorter than maximum line width

Finally, set **Indentation policy** to (thanks [@Turbo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275785/wrapping-chained-method-calls-on-a-separate-line-in-eclipse-for-java#comment16795333_10446098)):

> Indent on column

It should give you the exact behavior you asked for.

---

**BONUS: Android Studio / IntelliJ Idea:**

> **Mac OS**: Android Studio → Preferences (`Cmd +,`) → Editor → Code Style → Java → *Wrapping And Braces* tab → Chained method calls

select

> Wrap always

and check

> Align when multiline

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't work for `return new SomeClass().A().B().C();` with each method call on a separate line.

Comment: @ChristianGarcía +1 for the great answer. One observation from me (Eclipse neon): When I set `Indent on column`, it sometimes add extra space; for example `session.createQuery` becomes `session .createQuery` and so on. Reverting to the default option sorted the problem for me though.

Comment: This inserts a tab after the first invocation. To avoid it, I had to check "Use spaces to indent wrapped lines" under Indentation.

Comment: As @DanielNitzan mentioned, this will insert tabs. I solved this by not setting the indentation policy to "Indent by one" rather than "Indent on column". This makes it so that function calls one new lines will be indented one tab deeper than the start of the statement and not hang in the middle of the page

Comment: I don't see *indentation policy* :(* Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there a way to not wrap inside a statement? like in a `if (x.a().b() && y.c().d())` or a `while (x.a().b() && y.c().d())`

Comment: Is there a way to only wrap after two chained calls (wrap `test.toString().strip().strip()` but not `test.toString().strip()`) ?

Answer (score 16):

Window → Preferences → Java → Code Style → Formater → Edit → Line wrapping → Never join already wrapped lines

Comment: I am sorry i did not explain: It won't format it. It will simply not mess it up, if you do it manually.

Comment: I now understand. Eclipse can't actually format chained methods but it will retain the formatting as I have typed it. Thanks.

Comment: nothing specific to chained calls. If you force function call wrapping, it will wrap everywhere

Comment: @Johann That is not correct, Eclipse can format chained method calls.

Comment: @OpDeCirkel You should add your comment in the answer itself. Make it easier for people to notice it : This comment `I am sorry i did not explain: It won't format it. It will simply not mess it up, if you do it manually. –`

Answer (score 8):

Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formater > Edit > Line wrapping > Function Calls, set the 'Line wrapping policy' as 'Wrap all elements, every element on a new line'.

Comment: This will put on new line every function call, even if they are not chained, and if you format your file with Ctrl+Shift+f, it will mess up everything\

Comment: Other policies are also available, e.g. "Wrap all elements, except first element if not necessary". One of them should work for you :)

Answer (score 8):

For those who have eclipse code formatting settings checked into source control (for consistent code formatting across the whole team), the `.settings` folder is checked in.

The property that will give you this formatting behavior is in the `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file.

The property is:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_selector_in_method_invocation=80
```

Comment: `82` to be aligned exactly like he wants. [Eclipse Source](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core/formatter/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/formatter/DefaultCodeFormatterOptions.java#n38)

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to do the formatting of those segments yourself, you can prevent eclipse from reformatting those segments by using:

```
// @formatter:off
...
// @formatter:on
```

You might need to enable this in your preferences:
http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news-part2.html#JavaFormatter

See also:
[How to turn off the Eclipse code formatter for certain sections of Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1820908/364401)

Answer (score 0):

in: Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formater->Edit->Line wrapping->Function call-> Qualified invocation

select Indentation policy as indent on column

Answer (score -1):

Customize your eclipse formatter in both java and javascript. increase the max line with that fits your screen. [image: Windows>preferences]

[image: Edit]