# How to tell eclipse to not format parts of a codefile (pressing Strg + Shift + F)

Tags: eclipse, format

I really love the autofromat feature. I makes your code more readable and in case of JavaScript tells you, when there are synatcs errors (missing brackets etc.).

However sometimes the formatting makes the code harder to read. e.g. when it puts a long array inizalisation into a single line. In that case I don't want him to format it, but rather leave it ofer multiple lines.
E.g.

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'aloha', 
    'aloha/plugin', 
    'ui/ui', 
    'ui/scopes', 
    'ui/button', 
    'ui/toggleButton', 
    'ui/port-helper-attribute-field', 
    'ui/text'
// 'css!youtube/css/youtube.css'
], 
    function(
        $, 
        Aloha, 
        Plugin, 
        Ui, 
        Scopes, 
        Button, 
        ToggleButton, 
        AttributeField) 
        {
```

this array should stay like this and don't become this:

```
define(['jquery', 'aloha', 'aloha/plugin', 'ui/ui', 'ui/scopes', 'ui/button', 'ui/toggleButton', 'ui/port-helper-attribute-field', 'ui/text' ], function($, Aloha, Plugin, Ui, Scopes, Button, ToggleButton, AttributeField) {
```

Is there a special tag, to tell eclipse not to format the code?

Comment: Take a look at Eclipse formatter tags, see answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3353765/1288408

Comment: thanks that's what I was looking for. Well I don't want to delete this querstion, since I didn't find the link and I searched quite a while for it. Do you wanna sumerize the answer and I accept it? LG

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your comment. I think you should accept your own answer :)

Comment: ^^ ok, I was going to but since you brought me on the right track, I think you deserved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, it took me some time to find the right setting so I will post a toturial here.

Go to Window Preferences and Search the Formatter you are using. In my case it was under 'Aptana Studia' -> 'Formatter'. (Depending on your Package this differs, e.g. the Java Formatter is under 'Java' -> 'Code Style' -> 'Formater').

[image: Create new Formatter Proffile]

Noww create a new Build profile since you can't override the old one.

Now enable the Formatter tags.
[image: Enabale Formatter on/off tags]

Now you can use the

```
 - @formatter:on
 - @formatter:off
```

tags to disable code formatting.

Example:
this code:

```
    function hello() {             return 'hello';
}

//@formatter:off
/*
   |\      _,,,---,,_
   /,`.-'`'    -.  ;-;;,_
  |,4-  ) )-,_..;\ (  `'-'
 '---''(_/--'  `-'\_)  fL

 */
//@formatter:on

function 


world() {
    return 'world';
}
```

Will get formatted to like this

```
function hello() {
    return 'hello';
}

//@formatter:off
/*
   |\      _,,,---,,_
   /,`.-'`'    -.  ;-;;,_
  |,4-  ) )-,_..;\ (  `'-'
 '---''(_/--'  `-'\_)  fL

 */
//@formatter:on

function world() {
    return 'world';
}
```

Note how the function definition is formatted correct, while the ascii art isn't

Credits:

1. [Katja Christiansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288408/katja-christiansen) for his comment
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3353765/639035 : for a similar answer

Comment: Nice tutorial, I like the example :)

Comment: Tanks, botherd me far to long, so I had to document it^^

Comment: OK, if you are using [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/) this works. In an standard eclipse installation you won't have this option.

Comment: @user714965 - Eclipse Mars - I found under 'Edit' button in Preferences->Java->Code Style-> Formatter

Comment: Great! I`ll remove my last comment soon.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make an empty comment after each line:

```
define([ //
    'jquery', //
    'aloha', //
    'aloha/plugin', //
    'ui/ui', //
    'ui/scopes', //
    'ui/button', //
    'ui/toggleButton', //
...
```

Not nice, but I think it will work.

Comment: Works, but code gets somehow ugly. It formats them to the beginning of the document