# How to custom Eclipse's formatter about jQuery code

Tags: jquery, eclipse, formatting

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388185/how-to-tell-eclipse-to-not-format-parts-of-a-codefile-pressing-strg-shift-f/12401529#12401529) is nice, but instead of placing special tag comments everywhere, I look for a solution about jQuery code, more specifically the `$` character. Eclipse formatter does not seem to recognize

```
$.ajax({
```

and transforms it like this:

```
$
       .ajax({
```

Any clues other than changing all `$` to `jQuery`?

edit: I cannot find a minimal example... it seems to happen only on very big functions, with some big comments

Top of one of these big functions

```
function loadDataArt(id) {
    $.each(id, function(index) {
    $.ajax({
```

Is transformed into:

```
function loadDataArt(id) {
    $
        .each(
            id,
            function(index) {
            $
                .ajax({
```

Tabulations? I'll try to find out more info -_-

edit2: disabling line wrap was the solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This may be caused by the width of the line.  Try changing the amount of characters in a line in Eclipse, it still defaults to 80 which is a throw back to punch card days.

1. Windows > Preferences > Javascript > Code Style > Formatter > Edit
2. Change the profile name so it is not the built in Profile
3. Click the Line Wrapping Tab
4. Set the Max Line Width

[image]

Comment: You were right, disabling line wrap did the thing! It happens that I needed more than 250 chars/line...
Many thanks!