# Eclipse avoid line breaking for jmockit

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting, jmockit

Within Eclipse, is it possible to avoid line breaks for better jmockit readability without turning off the code formatter ?

Wanted:

```
@Test
public void testRegisterNodeModelFactory() {
  new Expectations() {{
    RepositoryManager.getInstance(); times = CALLED;
  }};

  invoke(_measureModuleInstall, "registerNodeModeFactory");
}
```

Currently:

```
@Test
public void testRegisterNodeModelFactory() {
  new Expectations() {{
    RepositoryManager.getInstance();
    times = CALLED;
  }};

  invoke(_measureModuleInstall, "registerNodeModeFactory");
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at turning off the formatter around those areas of code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820908/how-to-turn-off-the-eclipse-code-formatter-for-certain-sections-of-java-code

Comment: Yes, but I wanted something 'cleaner' ...

Comment: I have the same problem in IntelliJ IDEA that I have not been able to resolve, either.

Answer (score 0):

Disable code formatter for some parts of code:

```
// @formatter:off
RepositoryManager.getInstance(); times = CALLED;
// @formatter:on
```

Comment: This would disable whole formatter. Is it possible to disable line breaking only?