# Eclipse wraps NOPMD Tag after imports

Tags: eclipse, pmd, formatter

I have a little problem with Eclipse. When i set a `//NOPMD` tag behind an import it wraps the tag to the end of the imports. How can I avoid that eclipse wraps any `//NOPMD` tags during beautifying the java program?

**Example before beautifying:**

```
import java.io.IOException;//NOPMD
```

**Example after beautifying:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

//NOPMD
```

Comment: I found, that you can uncheck the Organzie imports box under window-->Preferences-->Java-->Editor-->Save actions to solve this problem, but that doesn't makes it better because i want Eclipse to organise the imports. Is there a possibility to say Eclipse that it should keep the //NOPMD tags untouched during beautifying?

Answer (score 0):

How about using @SupressWarnings("PMD.NameOfRule").  This will suppress all instances of that rule in the class which may or may not be what you want.  But it is immune to code reformatting and organize imports.

As a reference, here are the [options for suppressing.](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.4/suppressing.html)

Comment: The problem with the @SupressWarnings("PMD.NameOfRule") is, that it ignores all PMD warnings which I don't want. I just want to set the //NOPMD tags on specific warnings. If i use the @SupressWarnings method i don't even see if there are PMD warnings. So the problem is not to supress the PMD warnings the problem is that Eclipse moves the //NOPMD tags to a new line during beautifying which causes that the tag gets useless because i still get the tagged PMD warnings.

Comment: It would only suppress warnings on that rule type, not all warnings.  But there is a bigger problem with my suggestion.  Which is that you can't have @SuppressWarnings on imports.

Answer (score 0):

Found a better answer once I stopped looking at this as a PMD problem!  The [accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820908/how-to-turn-off-the-eclipse-code-formatter-for-certain-sections-of-java-code) shows how to turn off formatting on sections of the code by writing:

```
// @formatter:off
...
// @formatter:on
```

You'd need to do this on each class around your imports.  Or each class that has //NOPMD that is.  And you'd need to turn on the setting in your workspace.  And have your teammates to this same if you are on a team.