# Is it possible to mark a part of java code in eclipse to be not auto formatted?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, format, autoformatting

Auto-Format by eclipse for java code is brilliant! You can write terrible code and then simple type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> - and the code is amazing.

But, sometime I want to mark part of code to be not automatically formatted.
For example by fluent interface:

```
public void fluentInterfaceJooqDemo() {
    create.select(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME, count())
          .from(AUTHOR)
          .join(BOOK).on(AUTHOR.ID.equal(BOOK.AUTHOR_ID))
          .where(BOOK.LANGUAGE.eq("DE"))
          .and(BOOK.PUBLISHED.gt(date("2008-01-01")))
          .groupBy(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME)
          .having(count().gt(5))
          .orderBy(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME.asc().nullsFirst())
          .limit(2)
          .offset(1)
          .forUpdate()
          .of(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME);
}
```

and after type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

```
public void fluentInterfaceJooqDemo() {
    create.select(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME, count()).from(AUTHOR).join(BOOK).on(AUTHOR.ID.equal(BOOK.AUTHOR_ID))
            .where(BOOK.LANGUAGE.eq("DE")).and(BOOK.PUBLISHED.gt(date("2008-01-01"))).groupBy(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME)
            .having(count().gt(5)).orderBy(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME.asc().nullsFirst()).limit(2).offset(1).forUpdate()
            .of(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME);
}
```

However, I'm looking for some method to mark such code `non-autoformat`, e.g.

```
//non-format
public void fluentInterfaceJooqDemo() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820908/how-to-turn-off-the-eclipse-code-formatter-for-certain-sections-of-java-code

Comment: you can select the part you want to format and then press `CTRL + SHIFT + f` so only the selected part gets formated

Comment: Personally, I don't think tools that encourage writing "terrible code" are brilliant. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can use `@formatter:off` and `@formatter:on`

```
// @formatter:off
public void fluentIterfaceThingy() { 
...
}
// @formatter:on
```

You *might* have to turn this option on in the code style section: `Window->Preferences->Java->Formatter->Edit->On/Of Tags`

Comment: Thx, how turn this option on?

Comment: @Mark - Edited to highlight where that is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is configurable in eclipse. And you can redefine the on/off keywords.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is additional configuration needed (we have a customized eclipse in our company) but this works for me:

// @formatter:off
// @formatter:on