# How to prevent Eclipse from wrapping around sections of comments

Tags: eclipse, formatting, comments

My Eclipse formatter invoked on the save command is set to wrap lines of comments, as this is what I desire most of the time.  However, I occasionally want Eclipse NOT to wrap some lines of comments.  Here is an example.

If I write:

```
    /**
 * My Eclipse formatter is set to wrap lines of comments, as this is what I
 * desire most of the time. However, I occasionally want Eclipse NOT to wrap
 * some lines of comments such as when I provide a simple example of an
 * output format like here:
 * 
 * Example output:
 * <comments>
 *   <comment>This should be on one line</comment>
 *   <comment>And this on the next</comment>
 * </comments>
 * 
 */
```

the Eclipse formatter will turn this into:

```
/**
 * My Eclipse formatter is set to wrap lines of comments, as this is what I
 * desire most of the time. However, I occasionally want Eclipse NOT to wrap
 * some lines of comments such as when I provide a simple example of an
 * output format like here:
 * 
 * Example output: <comments> <comment>This should be on one line</comment>
 * <comment>And this on the next</comment> </comments>
 * 
 */
```

which I don't want. I know I can prevent each line to wrap with `<li>` as below but that gets cumbersome very quickly, makes the comments more confusing, and still does not prevent Eclipse from changing the indentation:

```
    /**
 * My Eclipse formatter is set to wrap lines of comments, as this is what I
 * desire most of the time. However, I occasionally want Eclipse NOT to wrap
 * some lines of comments such as when I provide a simple example of an
 * output format like here:
 * 
 * Example output:<li>
 * <comments><li>
 * <comment>This should be on one line</comment><li>
 * <comment>And this on the next</comment><li>
 * </comments><li>
 * 
 */
```

Is there something I could put before "Example output" to tell Eclipse to ignore the formatter so that it preserves the indentation and line wrapping I chose for a portion of my comments only?

Comment: Assuming this is for Java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820908/how-to-turn-off-the-eclipse-code-formatter-for-certain-sections-of-java-code .

Comment: Perfect. This was exactly what I was looking for.  What's the protocol here? Do you want to have this as an answer so that I check it? Or do we mark this question as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Increasing line width for comments in code style formatter should solve your problem.

Comment: No: I set my formatter exactly to the way I want. I just want to ignore it occasionally on portions of a file.

Comment: Eclipse 3.6 above allows ignoring or section of a code. Go to preference -> Code style -> Formatter. Edit the existing formatter. Go to Off/On tags. You can define your own tags and use it in comment to ignore that section from formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 3.6 above allows ignoring or section of a code. Go to preference -> Code style -> Formatter. Edit the existing formatter. Go to Off/On tags. You can define your own tags and use it in comment to ignore that section from formatting.

Comment: Yes. This is indeed what the answer that nitind pointed me to said. That is exactly what I had been looking for.