# Optimize / Improve my SQL update

Tags: java, mysql, sql, optimization

Okay, so let me just state this first. I am very new to SQL and I don't know a lot about it. I just recently started using it and I've been trying to learn it and improve. Please explain anything you state, as I may not understand common terms etc.

The SQL code I wrote now works like I intend it to, but the string seems obnoxious and made me think that this can't be quite right.

```
INSERT INTO reputations(uuid, warn, bandate, reasons, mods)
    VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', CONCAT(reasons, '{3}'), CONCAT(mods, '{4}'))
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE warn = '{1}',
                            bandate = '{2}',
                            reasons=CONCAT(reasons, '{3}'),
                            mods=CONCAT(mods, '{4}')
```

In my Java code it looks like this:
[image: SQL in Java]

As you also probably can see, I have no clue on how to properly format/indent it all for use like this. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

I should also explain that the `{n}`'s are just spaces where I replace it with the information I want. For example, I replace all {0} with an UUID.

So, my question is. Is there a better way to do this? Any tips or help would be appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: You just reinvented prepared statements, but without the robustness and the efficiency they provide. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: remenber to parameterised queries for sql injection

Comment: if you are using Eclipse, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820908/how-to-turn-off-the-eclipse-code-formatter-for-certain-sections-of-java-code) for how to disable the format so you can format the SQL as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand this part:

```
VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', CONCAT(reasons, '{3}'), CONCAT(mods, '{4}'))
------------------------------------^
```

The use of the column name there should be generating an error.

Perhaps this is the statement you want:

```
INSERT INTO reputations(uuid, warn, bandate, reasons, mods)
    VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE warn = VALUES(warn),
                            bandate = VALUES(bandate),
                            reasons = CONCAT(reasons, VALUES(reasons)),
                            mods = CONCAT(mods, VALUES(mods));
```

In the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` part, you can use `VALUES()` to get the new value from a particular column.  In addition, I suspect you might really want to have a separator for the last two concatenations:

```
                            reasons = CONCAT_WS('; ', reasons, VALUES(reasons)),
                            mods = CONCAT_WS('; ', mods, VALUES(mods));
```

The use of `CONCAT_WS()` has a nice side effect if the values are ever `NULL` -- it will still leave the remaining values.