# How to keep indentation hierarchies in fluent method chains on automatic formatting

Tags: java, eclipse, fluent

Say you have fluent method chains with meaningful indentations like:

```
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
```

Auto formatting in Eclipse creates the following, if you have "Never join already wrapped lines" active:

```
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
```

Because of that you are forced to decide between autoformatting a file containing fluent code and losing the meaningful indention hierarchy or giving up on automatic formatting...

I'd need the option "**don't change relative indentation for chained method calls**".

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: What you want is to locally-disable the Eclipse formatter. This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1820908/1743880

Comment: That's a nice work around. Would be really nice if you didn't need the ugly comments though

Comment: @formatter:off/on also works in Intellij.  I agree it's ugly, but at least it's somewhat standard.

Comment: You can formally answer the question if you want to. (;