# Is there a plugin to tell IntelliJ not to format a particular block when I use auto format?

Tags: intellij-idea

My question is a duplicate of: [How to turn off the Eclipse code formatter for certain sections of Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820908/how-to-turn-off-the-eclipse-code-formatter-for-certain-sections-of-java-code?rq=1) but for IntelliJ.

Does a similar feature exist for IntelliJ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and It works the same way with:

```
@formatter:off
```

and

```
@formatter:on
```

Navigate to:

Settings **>** Editor **>** Code Style **>** Formatter control

[image]

Comment: This breaks javadoc when used inside javadoc comments: `error: unknown tag: formatter:on`