# Can I change the eclipse formatter line width for a specific section of code?

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

Is there a way to change the line width for the java formatter for specific sections of code?

Something like @formatter:on/off, e.g. @formatter:width=200 ?

For reference: [How to turn off the Eclipse code formatter for certain sections of Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820908/how-to-turn-off-the-eclipse-code-formatter-for-certain-sections-of-java-code).

Usually I have a need for this for constants with long initializers. Currently I turn the formatter off and do it manually, but mainly to only just use 1 line per constant. The rest of the automatic formatting would be ok.

Comment: There is no support for this.

Comment: Seems [there is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3353765/2834978). Verified in Eclipse Oxygen java formatter configuration.