# google-java-format eclipse plugin ignoring formatter:off comments

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I'm using the google-java-format plugin here: https://github.com/google/google-java-format
in my eclipse STS (Version: 4.5.0.RELEASE)

When defining a Camel Java DSL Route , I am trying to ignore the formatter so I can have the following indented code:

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder
{

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception
  {
   super.configure();
   from("direct:myendpointh").routeId("foo")
    .setBody().method(MyClass.class, "calc(${body})")
    .setHeader("bar").method(BarCalc.class, "compute(${body})")
    .choice()
       .when().ognl("request.body.isConditionMet")
       .to("direct:ConditionalRoute").endChoice()
    .otherwise()
       .routingSlip(header("mySlip"))
    .end();
  }
}
```

Now If I change the formatter from eclipse to google-java-format:

[image]

*and* add the ignore format comments, following the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3353765/5198805)

it  **still**  formats with 1 method call per line, and loses the choice() indentation:

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder
{
  //@formatter:off
  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception
  {
   super.configure();
   from("direct:myendpointh")
    .routeId("foo")
    .setBody()
    .method(MyClass.class, "calc(${body})")
    .setHeader("bar")
    .method(BarCalc.class, "compute(${body})")
    .choice()
    .when()
    .ognl("request.body.isConditionMet")
    .to("direct:ConditionalRoute")
    .endChoice()
    .otherwise()
    .routingSlip(header("mySlip"))
    .end();
  }
  //@formatter:on
}
```

Is there a way to toggle formatters for a specific file ... e.g. disable google-java-format for certain files requiring method chained indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they didn't implement that. https://github.com/google/google-java-format/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-use-magic-comments-to-disable-formatting-for-certain-sections-of-code